# How do I change the location of a path after create in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a routes.rb file that looks like this:

```
namespace :api do
 namespace :v1 do
  resources :posts, except: [:new, :edit]
 end
end
```

This lets me generate URLs like "mywebsite.com/api/v1/posts" instead of just "mywebsite.com/posts" like the default.

My create method looks like this:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end
```

The `location: @post` worked great until I namespaced my URLs. How can I get the `location: @post` to reflect the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location: api_v1_post_path(@post)`

Answer (score 1):

If you run `rake routes` from the command line, you'll see how your routes have been affected by namespacing. The relevant route you're looking for will look something like this:

```
# rake routes
api_v1_post GET    /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)                       api/v1/posts#show
```

You'll see that your `show` action is now accessible via `api_v1_post`. In your controller, pass your `@post` instance variable to procure the correct route:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
render json: @post, status: :created, location: api_v1_post_path(@post)
```

Comment: In case anyone finds this answer later, `rake routes` were deprecated on rails 6.1 in favor of `rails routes`.